# How to include python PIL module without installation

Tags: python, import, python-imaging-library, python-module, imaging

I need to distribute some Python software which uses PIL, but to avoid installing PIL on every target machine. i have directory struct:

```
/myscript.py
/PIL/_imaging.so
/PIL/Image.py
/PIL/ImageFont.py
/PIL/ImageOps.py
etc
```

in `myscript.py` i imported:

```
import PIL.Image, PIL.ImageFont, PIL.ImageDraw, PIL.ImageOps
import PIL.JpegImagePlugin, PIL.PdfImagePlugin
```

but script execution says:

```
File "/Users/svp/git/multipdf-air/src/backend/mac-sl/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 148, in FreeTypeFont
def getmask2(self, text, mode="", fill=Image.core.fill):
File "/Users/svp/git/multipdf-air/src/backend/mac-sl/PIL/Image.py", line 37, in __getattr__
raise ImportError("The _imaging C module is not installed")
ImportError: The _imaging C module is not installed
```

I tried to import `_imaging`  module like `import PIL._imaging`, but this does not helps.

SO, how can i include this module without PIL installation?

Comment: Do you know that you cannot share a C-compiled extension between different Python versions and platforms?

Comment: you mean every OS version must have own _imaging compiled module? I need this for 2 OS versions: Mac Snow Leopard and Mac Lion. They have the same Python versions. I use separate PIL for them, but i need to include it in at least one version of Python.

Comment: Yes, probably. But I think the Python version is the problem in this case. Snow Leopard ships with 2.6 and Lion with 2.7. Or do you have a custom version installed?

Comment: I have both PIL versions in distribution and i will use PIL depended on OS version. This this is not problem. Problem now to execute script without system wide PIL installation.

Comment: you need to ship your software with the python version for which PIL lib was compiled in case the target has different python by default. The shipped python version has to be installed on the target. Your software has to be executed by this python. It's usually a lot of hassle. Keep in mind PIL is pretty old software and eventually incompatible with newer than 2.5* python